# How to debug AutoLayout Constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, autolayout, constraints

I am new to iOS Development. Whenever I run my App, I get this conflicting constraints error. Can you please suggest me something about how to debug this issue?

```
2016-07-13 12:53:51.186 Calculator[4458:50017] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fcaf3c5e670 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fcaf3c62a80(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fcaf3c5c060 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fcaf3c62a80.bottom == UIView:0x7fcaf3c54390.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcaf3c54b00 UIImageView:0x7fcaf3c54c70.width == UIImageView:0x7fcaf3c54c70.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcaf3c633d0 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fcaf3c54c70]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcaf3c54390 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcaf3c63420 H:[UIImageView:0x7fcaf3c54c70]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcaf3c54390 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcaf3c63470 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fcaf3c54c70]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcaf3c54390 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcaf3c63560 V:[UIImageView:0x7fcaf3c54c70]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fcaf3c62a80]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcaf3c67e50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fcaf3c54390(736)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcaf3c61230 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fcaf3c54390(414)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcaf3c54b00 UIImageView:0x7fcaf3c54c70.width == UIImageView:0x7fcaf3c54c70.height>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: You can see the one that Xcode had to break: `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcaf3c54b00 UIImageView:0x7fcaf3c54c70.width == UIImageView:0x7fcaf3c54c70.height>`
means that the constraint that was `imageView.width = imageView.height` broke

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to achieve? You want to have an UIImageView instead a UIView and the UIView has height = 736 and width = 414? The constraints break, because you can't have the UIImageView with equal width to height and match the edges of the UIView. I'm happy to post an example if you can clarify.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you have a constraint added which is being counter acted by another constraint.

Normally if you right click you're able to get the 'Suggested Constraints' try using them and see if it works!

edit:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Where should I right click?

Comment: please check my edit! I added a photo in for you to look at

Comment: I think it worked, but I didn't really understand what the problem was. Is there anyway we can find out what the actual problem was?

Comment: I assume it was a constraint being counter acted by another one, it seemed that it was something to do with the height and width of an image. Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did, I would mark your answer as solution as soon as I am allowed to do so.

Comment: Glad to hear! If you get stuck with anything else feel free to drop a message here!